# htaccess mistake & How to force the client's browser to clear the cache?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made a terrible mistake, 
And set long expire date to my files (including index.php).

```
   ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 3 week"
```

Now a lot of my users get the old file and because it's the index file of the directory I can't use ?v=1 trick.

I don't want to rename the directory because of SEO reasons.

Is there is any other option?

Comment: Not really. You _told_ clients, “hey don’t bother to check this again for at least three weeks, it’s gonna be good for that long”, so that is likely what they are going to do.

Comment: You can't do anything if the browser isn't going to contact your server for updated instructions because it already has the cached data…

Comment: OMG. RewriteRule to another folder will solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to move it to another folder. With the updated index.php file.

In three weeks, remove redirect to sub folder and update the original index.php.Try a 302 redirect.`Redirect 302 / /tempfolder`

Comment: what is the RewriteRule for that?

Comment: I posted the rule above.